# How can I load an MS Excel file, add content and send to user?

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I need to load a template MS Excel file, add content to some cells and then download it via the user's browser, so he can open and/or save the file.

I managed to create some MS Excel workbooks in the past, but this seems somewhat different. How could I do it?

Thanks in advance,

gtludwig

Comment: you will probably have great luck trying one of the many examples that the apache poi project has on their site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are good tutorials on apache-poi on their official site

```
final Workbook wb;
fileIn =new FileInputStream(fname);
wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn);//opening a file
final Sheet sheet = wb.createsheet("Report");// create a sheet
```

Then use [Row](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html) and [Cell](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) classes to add contents in cell

```
Row row;
Cell cell;
row=sheet.getRow(0); //get existing row
if(row==null)
row=sheet.createRow(0);//if row not present create row
cell=row.getCell(0);
if(cell==null)
cell=row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(0);//set cell value
```

**UPDATE :** I forgot to mention that you need to write contents on file

```
fout=new FileOutputStream(fname);
wb.write(fout);
```

and then close fout in `finally` block

```
if(fout!=null)
fout.close();
```

Once you are done with the excel file create a download servlet

```
File file=new File(fname);
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);

        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                             "attachment;filename="+fname+".xlsm");
            ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), 1024 * 10);
            OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), 1024 * 10);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 10];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
        fis.close();
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, thanks! Will accept the answer once I can verify it's what I need. I might have misexpressed myself! :)

Comment: OK, it works! But when opened, the new file is always read-only and does not have the data I inserted.

Comment: check your file on server side..does he have data...did you close the file in java properly?

Comment: I got it working! I missed a (Workbook) workbook.write((OutputStream) outStream); somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Excel supports plain plat CSV format, insert your data into CSV is the simples way IMO. If there are complex format in your document than CSV can handle, Office Automation maybe a  choise. VBA is strong enough langauge and you can manipulate Excel sheet easily. HTH